# Assignment through smart pointer to class members

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, dereference

I'm still quite new to C++, and when I was exploring smart pointers, there was a behavior that I couldn't fully understand.

Consider the following simple class:

```
class Student {

public:
    int studentID;
    string gender;
    string name;

    Student(int studentID, string gender, string name)
    {
        this->studentID = studentID;
        this->gender = std::move(gender);
        this->name = std::move(name);
    }

    unique_ptr<string> getNameUnique()
    {
        return make_unique<string>(this->name);
    }

    string* getNamePtr()
    {
        return &name;
    }

};
```

In the main code, if I get the smart pointer that points to the `name` of an instance and try to modify it, it won't work:

```
auto nameUniquePtr = mary.getNameUnique();
cout << "Before: " << mary.name << "\n";
cout << "Before (through pointer): " << *nameUniquePtr << "\n";
*nameUniquePtr = "Tracy";
cout << "After: " << mary.name << "\n";
cout << "After (through pointer): " << *nameUniquePtr << "\n\n";
```

produces:

```
Before: Mary
Before (through pointer): Mary
After: Mary
After (through pointer): Tracy
```

Apparently, the `name` member of `mary` wasn't changed. When stepping through the debug tools, I found that the addresses the smart pointer pointed to and the actual address of the member weren't even the same. However, if I directly get the pointer to the same member and try to change the value of it, it works:

```
auto namePtr = mary.getNamePtr();
cout << "Before: " << mary.name << "\n";
cout << "Before (through pointer): " << *namePtr << "\n";
*namePtr = "Tracy";
cout << "After: " << mary.name << "\n";
cout << "After (through pointer): " << *namePtr << "\n\n";
```

produces:

```
Before: Mary
Before (through pointer): Mary
After: Tracy
After (through pointer): Tracy
```

Even if I directly set a smart pointer variable that points to the member and change the value through it, it still won't work:

```
auto directPtr = make_unique<string>(mary.name);
cout << "Before: " << mary.name << "\n";
*directPtr = "Jessica";
cout << "After: " << mary.name << "\n\n";
```

produces:

```
Before: Tracy
After: Tracy
```

Are there some specifications or limitations when smart pointers are used to point to class members? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
return make_unique<string>(this->name);
```

You are not returning a pointer to `name`  You create a `std::unique_ptr<std::string>` that holds it's own `std::string` that is a copy of `name`.  it is completely separate from `name`.

You could create a `unique_ptr` that has a null deleter and construct it with a pointer to `name` but that is a lot of work when you could simply return `name` by reference to get a handle to it.

---

I would also like to point out that you should use a [member initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to initialize your class members.  What you are doing is assinging in the constructor body which is not as efficent.  For you that would look like

```
Student(int studentID, string gender, string name) : studentID(studentID), gender(std::move(gender)), name(std::move(name)) {}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it why that if I set a unique_ptr<Student> variable by doing this: `auto student = make_unique<Student>(mary)`, and explicit set the copy constructor in the `Student` class, when this variable is assigned, the copy constructor is called? That unique_ptr actually holds its own instances?

Comment: @GaryC. Yes.  If whatever you pass to `make_unique` is used to construct whatever type `make_unique` is making.  for instance `int foo; auto bar = make_unique<int>(foo);` initializes a new `int` that is a copy of `foo`

Answer (score 1):

When you are using your smart pointer, you create a new instance of the smart pointer with the value of `name` each time, so your pointer is never actually referring to the memory address of the member variable `name` but the copy you created. In more annotated terms:

```
unique_ptr<string> getNameUnique()
{
    return make_unique<string>(this->name); //copy the value of name into a new object that is a smart pointer
}
```

You might consider using a `shared_ptr` instead, like so:

```
class Student {

public:
  std::shared_ptr<std::string> name;      
  //.. other member variables

  Student(int studentID, string gender, string name)
  {
    //same as before except for
    this->name = std::make_shared<std::string>(name);
  }

  shared_ptr<std::string> getNameShared()
  {
     return this->name;
  }
  //otherwise the same
};
```

This will store the value of `name` in a smart pointer within the class. This `shared_ptr` can then be returned from your member function and the owner of that return value will have pointer to the same memory space that is owned by your `Student` instance. Then if you modify the contents of this smart pointer outside of the class, you will observe that change also within the `name` member variable.

Answer (score 1):

It might help your understanding of what's going on if you consider that the code:

```
return make_unique<string>(this->name);
```

is equivalent to:

```
std::unique_ptr<string> p;

p.reset(new string(this->name));

return p;
```